# Does Swift or Ceph have "Vault Lock"-like capabilities?

Tags: backup, storage, openstack, archive, ceph

AWS Glacier offers Vault Lock, which enables compliance policies like “write once read many” (WORM). Google Cloud Platform Storage [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146860/prevent-objects-deletion-from-google-storage). Does OpenStack Swift or Ceph offer any similar compliance features out of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openstack Swift appears to [not have immutability yet](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/swift/+spec/immutability-middleware). [Neither does CEPH](http://tracker.ceph.com/projects/ceph/wiki/Add_new_feature_-_Write_Once_Read_Many_volume). There are object options for WORM, but most places just use one of the more traditional NAS options. Most enterprise storage vendors have a WORM offering that's got a track record of compliance.